# How to have find recurse into subdirectories when using -prune option

Tags: bash, centos, find

I see that the `find` command does **not** descend into subdirectories when you're using the `-prune` option.  How do I tell find to recurse into the sub directories, but also ignore some stuff?

Specifically, I want to search the `/var/lib/foo` directory, but exclude any directories with the name `.snapshot/`.

```
sudo find /var/lib/foo -prune -name '.snapshot'
```

With the above, it properly ignores .snapshot, but doesn't go into the sub dirs. FYI, I'm working in bash on a CentOS 6.3 host.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do:

```
sudo find /var/lib/foo -name '.snapshot' -prune -o -print
```

it will print whatever is not named ".snapshot", and if ".snapshot" is a directory it will also not descend into it.

why ?  because "-prune" is an action (as '-print' is also another action), doing nothing except preventing to go further down in the subdir. And it always return "true", so here,  ( -name ... -prune ) is true if and only if the file or dir is named "...", and you you want everything else, hence the -o ( -print ).

Comment: I found [this nice so answer by @Laurence Gonsalves](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1489405/1841533) which explains it so much better (including a nice warning about not adding the -print)

Comment: Works perfect, thanks Olivier.  I tend to forget the ordering of things with the `find` command, such as actions.

Comment: parenthesis also helps :  `find /someplace \( some tests [and actions] \) -o \( some other tests [and actions] \)` , with possibility of multiple layers of parenthesis.